# Unit Testing GetByIdAsync method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

As part of validation for my site there is a method for checking whether an Id already exists with the following method:

```
        private async Task<bool> IdExistsAsync(Guid id)
        {
            var model = await repository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            return model != null;
        }
```

and in the constructor of the class the rule is set that states that the new id cannot match an existing one:

```
       public ValidatorBase(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IAsyncRepository<T> repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;

            if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
            {
                RuleFor(model => model.Id).MustAsync(async (Id, cancellation) => !await IdExistsAsync(Id))
                    .WithMessage(string.Format("{0} Id already exists.", typeof(T).Name));
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to do now is unit test this method, this is based off a file called DisciplineValidator which extends the validatorBase class.

I have created some mock disciplines:

```
        private static List<Discipline> testDisciplines = new List<Discipline>()
        {
            new Discipline
            {
                Id = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"),
                Code = "001"
            },
            new Discipline
            {
                Id = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"),
                Code = "002"

            },

            new Discipline
            {
                Id = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003"),
                Code = "003"

            }

        };
```

I have created a test like so:

```
        public void UniqueIdCheckTest() 
        {

            Discipline disciplineToTest = new Discipline()
            {
                Id = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")
            };

            var httpContextAccessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            httpContextAccessorMock.Setup(h => h.HttpContext.Request.Method).Returns(HttpMethods.Post);


            var disciplineRepositoryMock = new Mock<IAsyncRepository<Discipline>>();
            disciplineRepositoryMock.Setup(t => t.GetByIdAsync(disciplineToTest.Id, default));

            var disciplineValidator = new DisciplineValidator(httpContextAccessorMock.Object, disciplineRepositoryMock.Object);

            // Act
            var result = disciplineValidator.TestValidate(disciplineToTest);

            // Assert
            result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(discipline => discipline.Id)
                .WithErrorMessage("Discipline id already exists.");

        }
```

The issue I am having is, I am not sure how setup my disciplineRepositoryMock properly I know that:

```
            disciplineRepositoryMock.Setup(t => t.GetByIdAsync(disciplineToTest.Id, default));
```

is not correct and there should be more to it, I thought it should be something along the lines of:

```
            disciplineRepositoryMock.Setup(t => t.GetByIdAsync(disciplineToTest.Id, default))
                .ReturnsAsync(testDisciplines
                .Where(d => d.Id == disciplineToTest.Id).ToList());
```

But I then get the following error:

"Isetup<IAsyncRepository, Task> does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync'...."

So my question is, how do I set this up properly so that it it testing the GetByIdAsync method? Where is is that I'm going wrong?

Edit:

I have now updated my disciplineRespositoryMock like so:

```
    disciplineRepositoryMock.Setup(t => t.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<ISpecification<Discipline>>(), default))
        .ReturnsAsync(testDisciplines
        .Single(d => d.Id == disciplineToTest.Id));
```

There are no compiling errors but when I run the test, it fails with the message:

Message: 
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

What is the issue now?

Comment: This is using Moq, isnt'?

Comment: I would advise not doing database calls in a validation step.

Comment: yeah you're right @Julian it, I've added it to the tags

Comment: what would you suggest instead @Neil? But in terms of the test do you have any advice on how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put actual parameter values into the Setup expression, or the `It.Is...` matching code.

I always use `Returns`/`ReturnsAsync` with function, like:

```
(id, ct) => testDisciplines
            .Single(d => id == d.Id) 
// todo: return 404 status if not existing
```

Or I return tasks via Returns() for async methods:

```
(id, ct) => Task.FromResult(testDisciplines
            .Single(d => id == d.Id))
```

or

```
(id, ct) => Task.Run(() => testDisciplines
            .Single(d => id == d.Id), ct)
```

I found `ReturnsAsync` didn't work for me in a parallel test (was synchronized), while `Returns` with `Task` did.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I have updated my question with what I have done based on your answer, would you be able to have a look and advise on where it is I have gone wrong?